# How to Convert Hierarchical Data into XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

sample Input Table Details:

[image: Table Details]

Expected Output:

```
<Geo>
    <Continent Name="Asia">
        <Country Name="China">
            <State Name="Bejing"></State>
        </Country>
        <Country Name="Japan">
            <State Name="Tokyo"></State>
        </Country>  
    </Continent>
    <Continent Name="Europe">
        <Country Name="Germany">
            <State Name="Berlin"></State>
        </Country>
        <Country Name="France">
            <State Name="Paris"></State>
        </Country>  
    </Continent>
</Geo>
```

How to convert Input relation Data as Above Output XML?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```sql
create table #continents (
    continentid int, [continent name] nvarchar(100))
insert into #continents
SELECT  1, 'Asia'
UNION ALl
SELECT  2, 'Europe'
UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'Africa'

CREATE TABLE #countries (countryid int, [country name] nvarchar(100), continentid INT)

insert into #countries
SELECT  1,'China', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'Japan', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'Germany', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 'France', 2

CREATE TABLE #states (stateId INT, [State Name] nvarchar(100), countryid INT)

INSERT INTO #states
SELECT  1, 'Tokya', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'Berlin', 3
UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'Paris', 4
UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 'Bejing', 1


select  c.[Continent Name] AS [@Name]
,   (
    select cc.[Country Name] AS [@Name]
    ,   (
        SELECT  [State Name] AS [@Name]
        FROM    #states ss
        WHERE   ss.countryId = cc.countryId
        FOR XML PATH('State'), TYPE
    )
    FROM    #countries cc
    WHERE   cc.continentId = c.continentId
    FOR XML PATH('Country'), TYPE
    )
from    #continents c
for xml Path('Continent'), ROOT('Geo'), TYPE
```

Btw, next time, try to post data as create / insert script, instead of a screenshot, it really saves a lot of typing

Comment: "it really saves a lot of typing" also means "people are more likely to answer your question since they don't have to do a bunch of work before even starting to try!".

Comment: Apologies. Yesterday, All our Cloud and VDI were down. I'm unable to prepare an insert script.

Answer (score 1):

I was just too late copying all the data....

```
WITH Continent AS (
   SELECT 1 as Continent_ID, 'Asia' as Continent_Name
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 'Europe'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 3,'Africa'),
Country AS (
   SELECT 1 as Country_ID, 'China' as Country_Name, 1 as Continent_ID
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,'Japan', 1
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3, 'Germany', 2),
State AS (
   SELECT 1 as State_ID, 'Tokya' as State_Name, 2 as Country_ID
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 'Berlin', 3 )
select Continent_Name, Country_Name, State_Name
from Continent
inner join Country on Country.Continent_ID = Continent.Continent_ID
inner join State ON State.Country_ID = Country.Country_ID FOR XML AUTO, Root('Geo'), TYPE;
```

output (after formatting):

```
<Geo>
    <Continent Continent_Name="Asia">
        <Country Country_Name="Japan">
            <State State_Name="Tokya"/>
        </Country>
    </Continent>
    <Continent Continent_Name="Europe">
        <Country Country_Name="Germany">
            <State State_Name="Berlin"/>
        </Country>
    </Continent>
</Geo>
```

More info: [FOR XML (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

> A SELECT query returns results as a rowset. You can optionally
> retrieve formal results of a SQL query as XML by specifying the FOR
> XML clause in the query. The FOR XML clause can be used in top-level
> queries and in subqueries. The top-level FOR XML clause can be used
> only in the SELECT statement. In subqueries, FOR XML can be used in
> the INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements. FOR XML can also be used in
> assignment statements.